# Why isn't equals() method working on Threads?

Tags: java, equals, java-threads

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        Thread t2 = new Thread();
        Thread t3 = t1;

        String s1 = new String();
        String s2 = new String();

        System.out.println(t1 == t3);  //true
        System.out.println(t1 == t2);  //false

        **System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));  //false**
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true
    }
}
```

As we know, `Object.equals()` method is used for checking the content rather than the reference. So when you create two threads and perform `equals()` on them, what exactly is happening?

I assumed threads work differently. (I'm a beginner)

How do they work?

Comment: Why do you expect the result to be? Why would two distict `Thread` instances ever to `equal`? What would that mean?

Comment: It looks like [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) just inherits its `equals` method from `Object`, so under the hood it's doing reference comparison.

Comment: Didn't you try to look at the sources/docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what `equals` does.

I suppose that you learned that `equals` can be used to compare strings on a character by character basis instead of comparing them by their references. Then you thought, okay, so `equals` can compare stuff like that!

And then, you thought that these two threads are the same:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();
```

"because look! They are created the same way - with `new Thread()`. So they should be `equal`!" you thought.

However, `equals` does not think the two threads are equal. In fact, `Thread` does not even override `equals` (`String` does)! Therefore, it uses the `equals` implementation from its superclass, `Object`, which compares the references.

Therefore, `equals` is not like some "magical" thing that compares objects "logically". It has to be overridden in subclasses. It does not always work where you want it to.

Another example would be `Scanner`, which does not override `equals` either.

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner("Hello");
Scanner s2 = new Scanner("Hello");
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // false
```

`s1` and `s2` has exactly the same string to scan and they are at exactly the same position of the string, yet they are not equal when you compare them with `equals`.